# Documenting namepaces in Doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I'm starting documenting all of my code with doxygen. I´ve no problem with file documentation but i runinto a small problem when generating documentation for several files.

For example:

In some header files (I´m using only C/C++ code projects) i have the following code:

```
#include "../config/compiler.h"  ///< Compiler flags

namespace nge                    ///< NGE namespace
{
... some code...
}
```

After running doxywizard if I look for the documentation for namepaces I will see the NGE namespace but instead of getting:

```
NGE | NGE namespace
```

I get

```
NGE | Compiler flags
```

this occurs even if I swap `/// NGE namespace` with `/// @namespace NGE namespace`

Cam somebody please explain me where I´m making the mistake ??

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? To the best of my knowledge the `#include` cannot be documented in doxygen and doxygen will keep this documentation "in memory" and add it tho the next item it finds.

Comment: My doxygen version is 1.8.16 for Windows x86

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem of the "Compiler flags" is indeed that `#include` cannot be documented and that the comment (including the `<`) flows into the brief description of the next item (i.e. `namespace NGE`). The fact that the documentation of the `namespace NGE` also has the extra `<` is due to the fact that the `///<` is used for documenting after an complete item and in this case the definition of the namespace is not complete yet.